# Does postman allow building form like this?

Tags: postman

Say I have api that returns form data.  Data is not important here but will postman allow the following:

```
<form action="{{result.FormAction}}">
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{result.Name}}">
</form>
```

So the api will return data to be put into the form?
I can't find any articles or maybe searching for wrong thing.

Would I need to do this by JavaScript from Postman?

**Problem**
There is an API that requires a form post.  This API is 3rd party so in the UI (this all works).  The part of the form is generated by the API and fields are added to the form before it is posted from the client side.  Our API returns the form action along with the fields that are generated on the server side.

So for my example above I am wondering if this could be tested by Postman.  It's not critical as it all works well on the client side but would be nice to be able to run a few tests using Postman.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. This is the first time I hear 'api that returns form data'. Can you re-explain that step-by-step, what you get and what you want?

Comment: Basically, you want to test 3rd API. In FE, you fill the form and send the request? So I think you can open devtool chrome and see this request, copy as cURL (bash) then import to postman.